# Peticiones http en ionic status 200 pero lanza error Http failure during parsing for

Tags: android-studio, angular, ionic, http, capacitor

Estoy haciendo una app ionic con capacitor desde angular, El problema es que el tipo de objeto que recibe el back es application/json. Investigue hacerca del error y surge cuando se esta enviando el tipo erroneo para hacer la peticion, en web todo funciona con normaidad y cuando corro la app en el emulador o en el dispositvo, lanzaba ese error. intente pasar el content-type a tipo texto en mis servicios y desaparecia el error, pero no guardaba ni traia corectamente la peticion porque lo que en realidad recibe es un Json.

si envio mis servicios de esta manera,desaparece el error http failure during parsing:
[image: Peticion sin error pero no devulve valor]

De esta manera sale el error en android studio pero en web hace todo correctamente:

[image: Peticion con error que trae la informacion correctamente]

Esto es lo que recibe mi Backend

[image: Schema request]

Las peticiones se tiene status 200 pero sale el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lei tambien que esto se podia solucionar con el plugin de cordova Whitelist, pero dice que esta obsoleto, ademas mi emulador es android 10.0 y desde esa version este plugin dice que no es necesario.

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda, porque no doy con la solucion.

Comment: {email} creo que deberias cambiarlo por el email del usuario ya que lo normal se especifica asi las variables el swagger que has puesto de ejemplo.

Comment: María, has podido solucionar el error?... llevo varias semanas con el mismo error, misma respuesta... pero no he encontrado la solución. Tengo lo mismo, una app en Ionic con Angular y Capacitor. Conectando a un backend fuera de localhost. No sé si es un tema de proxy o ¿qué?.... en web funciona, pero ya en el dispositivo me da mensaje 200 pero marca error.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que esperas obtener un json pero obtienes una respuesta diferente, simplemente define `responseType` con valor `json` en tu petición en lugar de `text`:

```
{responseType: 'json'}
```

> `responseType`: especifica el formato en el cual retornara la petición

Comment: Hola, lo intente y sigo obteniendo el mismo error